# Creating <td> dynamically using jquery. Unexpected results in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, internet-explorer-11

I'm writing a dashboard of sorts. Multiple API calls are made and based on the results, I dynamically create the elements on the screen.

This works 100% as expected in Chrome 56, Firefox ESR 45.7.x and Microsoft Edge.
The culprit is IE 11 (which I still need to support, unfortunately).

When the cells are dynamically created (look for the line starting with 'var col1LED'), for some reason it only works on the **second (and those that follow)** iteration(s) of the $.each. In the first iteration, the values for **key** is present (I've checked using console.log) but the resulting *td* objects are empty.

I'm at a loss of where to look next. I've Google'd and searched this *at leborem* without any significant results.

The following is a copied directly from the dashboard code (with obvious sensitive names/calls changed).

```
/* ... this happens inside the '.done' of another ajax call */
dataTable = $("#tblData");
$.each(response.data, function(row, key)
{
    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: url.origin + "/API/v1/objects/" + key.ID,
      data: { type: "wlc", identifier_type: "wlcap", status: "0" },
        }).done(function(apResponse){
            /*  Determine the status for each AP found
                Status values for each
                1 - Active and associated
                2 - Disassociated
                3 - Downloading
                all that don't match go to 'u' for 'unknown;'
            */
            var status_1 = 0;
            var status_2 = 0;
            var status_3 = 0;
            var status_u = 0; //Unknown
            $.each(apResponse.data, function(apRow, apKey){
                switch (apKey.status){
                    case "1":
                        status_1 += 1;
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        status_2 += 1;
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        status_3 += 1;
                        break;
                    default:
                        status_u += 1;
                        break;
                }
            })

            /* Once all the AP statusses have been tallied, write the info for the specific node */
            var ledFile = "LEDgreen.svg";
            var cssClass = "table-cell-black";
            if (status_2 != 0)
            {
                ledFile = "LEDred.svg";
                cssClass = "table-cell-critical";
            } else if (status_3 != 0) {
                ledFile = "LEDorange.svg";
                cssClass = "table-cell-warning";
            } else {
                    ledFile = "LEDgreen.svg";
                cssClass = "table-cell-black";
                }

            clearPanel("#tblController"); //First clear any existing data using seperate function

            /* Create headers for table */
            var colHead1LED = $('<th></th>').addClass('table-header table-cell-center').html('');
            var colHead2wlcDetail = $('<th></th>').addClass('table-header table-cell-left').html('');
            var colHead3APOK = $('<th></th>').addClass('table-cell table-cell-center').html('<div title="Active and Asssociated">A/A</div>');
            var colHead4APDown = $('<th></th>').addClass('table-cell table-cell-center').html('<div title="Disassociated">D/A</div>');
            var colHead5APTotal = $('<th></th>').addClass('table-cell table-cell-center').html('<div title="Downloading">D/L</div>');
            var colHead6APExtra = $('<th></th>').addClass('table-cell table-cell-center').html('<div title="Total">Total</div>');

            /* Add new row */
            var headerRow = $('<tr></tr>');
            /* Append each of the cells/headers to the header row */
            headerRow.append(colHead1LED);
            headerRow.append(colHead2wlcDetail);
            headerRow.append(colHead3APOK);
            headerRow.append(colHead4APDown);
            headerRow.append(colHead5APTotal);
            headerRow.append(colHead6APExtra)
            /* Add row to table */
            dataTable.append(headerRow);

            /* Create cells */          
            var col1LED = $('<td></td>').addClass('table-cell table-cell-center').html('<img class="LED" style="width:1.0em;height:1.0em;" title="Status" src="resources/images/'+ ledFile +'">');
            var col2wlcDetail = $('<td></td>').addClass('table-cell ' + cssClass).html('<a href="#" onClick="getWlcApList(\'' + key.ID + '\',\''+ key.description + '\',\''+ key.ip + '\', 0);" title="' + key.description + ' (' + key.ip + ')">' + key.description + ' (' + key.ip + ')</a>');
            var col3APOK = $('<td></td>').addClass('table-cell table-cell-center').html('<button onClick="getWlcApList(\'' + key.ID + '\',\''+ key.description + '\',\''+ key.ip + '\', 1);" class="button-success">' +status_1 + '</button>');
            var col4APDown = $('<td></td>').addClass('table-cell table-cell-center').html('<button onClick="getWlcApList(\'' + key.ID + '\',\''+ key.description + '\',\''+ key.ip + '\', 2);" class="button-danger">' +status_2 + '</button>');
            var col5APTotal = $('<td></td>').addClass('table-cell table-cell-center').html('<button onClick="getWlcApList(\'' + key.ID + '\',\''+ key.description + '\',\''+ key.ip + '\', 3);" class="button-warning">' +status_3 + '</button>');
            var col6APExtra = $('<td></td>').addClass('table-cell table-cell-center').html('<button onClick="getWlcApList(\'' + key.ID + '\',\''+ key.description + '\',\''+ key.ip + '\', 0);" class="button-info">' + (status_1 + status_2 + status_3) + '</button>');


            /* Create data row */
            var dataRow = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('table-row-data');

            /* Add cells to row*/
            dataRow.append(col1LED);
            dataRow.append(col2wlcDetail);
            dataRow.append(col3APOK);
            dataRow.append(col4APDown);
            dataRow.append(col5APTotal);
            dataRow.append(col6APExtra);

            /* add row to array*/
            tableWlcData.push(dataRow);


            }).promise().done(function(){
                /* Once everything is done, append the array of ROWS to the table */

                dataTable.append(tableWlcData);


            });
});
```

Comment: Have you considered using some kindof templating library like handlebars? Moves all the HTML elements you are constructing out of your JS code which can make it alot cleaner and easy to debug

Comment: I've absolutely considered it, but unfortunately this is an extension on some proprietary software. I'm not allowed to add any new things in. Need to use existing libraries and functions. @milney

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line was the culprit:

```
 clearPanel("#tblController"); //First clear any existing data using seperate function
```

This is a function which simply does the following:

```
function clearPanel(elementId)
{
    $(elementId).html('');
}
```

Not sure why this caused an issue, but I changed the loop to only do the `clearPanel` if I am on row '0'.

Now working

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason could be that you're running the AJAX request on each loop which is synchronous, and using the value of "key" inside the success callback of each request, which is asynchronous, and thus the scope of `key` is lost.

If that doesn't fix the issue please post a fiddle with the HTML and the rest of the context (with dummy data if needed) and I'll be glad to review in detail for you. Still, you should keep the self calling function just for the sake of proper and stable Javascript code.

---

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

Try adding this inside the final promise():

```
var html = tableWlcData.join("\n");
console.log(html);
dataTable.html(html);
```

If setting the HTML of the table directly into the table rather than appending it as an array via the jQuery object doesn't fix it in IE, then please review the HTML printed to the console and check for any malformed HTML that may be causing IE11 to choke up.

Also, be sure you're using the latest version of jQuery (current version is 3.1.1), just in case there's an IE-specific bug in the version you're using.

Comment: edit: apologies, that was messy - I'm working on JSFiddle at the moment

Comment: Please have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/techedemic/1fx77vy8/1/

You won't be able to 'run' it...there are too many other components at play on this page...

But that is the entire function. Also check out the ouput of console.log at the bottom of the JS. That output is the same in all versions of all browsers (that I have available)

Comment: I see. When you inspect the first row of the table in IE 11, are the `<td>` nodes literally empty? Or are just the buttons inside those cells empty?

Comment: The `<td>` nodes are literally empty...it's weird...I've tried it on a plethora of browsers (including mobile derivatives) and IE 11 seems to be the only culprit